# How to get all sites where current user is Site Owner using Content Search Web Part in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint

I have one requirement where using CSWP I want to show all sites where current logged in user is Site Owner. As per my investigation there is one Managed Property named 'SiteOwners' which may give me my result, but there is not Crawl Property associated with this Managed Property. Can any one please help me?

I also want to show all sites where current logged in user is Site Member. There is another Managed Property 'SiteMembers' again there is no Crawl Property associated with this Managed Property. Then how to get result?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have to get sites from Search, You can get sites with a usercontrol.

This is for the site members all webs;

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("rootSite"))
{ 
   SPWebCollection UserSites = site.OpenWeb().GetSubwebsForCurrentUser();
   foreach (SPWeb web in UserSites)
   {
    //each Web
   }
});
```

Not: site Owners are member of all subsites so you can use the same code for a site owner.